# @feathersjs/socketio-client connection timeout. Why?

Tags: feathersjs

I maked follow:

```
 feathers g app # with socket and rest
 feathers g service # todos & NeDB
 npm start
```

and simple client for this. I copy code from documentation 
https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/socketio.

```
 const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
 const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio-client');
 const io = require('socket.io-client');

 const socket = io('http://localhost:3030');
 const app = feathers();

 app.configure(socketio(socket));


 app.service('todos')
   .on('created', message => console.log('New message created', message));

 app.service('todos').find().then(r => {
    console.log(r)
 }).catch(e => console.log('error',e))

 app.service('todos').create({
   title: 'A message from a REST client'
 });
```

this client code get me timeout errors for find() and create() methods

But if I make POST request by CURL, I have *onCreated* message in console

Why I got errors on create() and find() calls?

UPDATE:

I maked git repo for easy reproduce this problem
https://github.com/tolyanor/feathersjs-error

UPDATE2:

I change autogenerated file src/app.js like in feathers example chat application https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/master/src/app.js

Now I CAN call service method create on client, but CAN NOT receive *onCreated* message. So, this code

```
 app.service('/todos')
     .on('created', message => console.log('New todos created', message));
```

never calling

Answer (score 2):

You are using a Feathers v3 client with a Feathers v2 server. Old clients will be backwards compatible with new servers but *not* the other way around. Follow the [migration guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/migrating.html) to upgrade your server or generate a new application using `@feathersjs/cli` (`feathers --version` on the command line should show `v3.5.0` or later).

Comment: Thanks. I will try later